# Input field is not aligning correctly at breakpoint

Tags: html, css

I am creating a basic form containing 3 input fields. Everything is fine but when I shrink my window, the `submit` button is positioned oddly with the email field(before `516px`, after `768px`). Before it reaches breakpoint `516px`, it works ok. But isn't it supposed to stay in `center` **before** `768px` as I declared breakpoint at `768px`?

HTML:

```
<div class="header-form header-flex">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="submit"> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

.header-form input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=submit] {
  width: 70%;
}

.header-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngq7edc8/9/

So what can I do now?

Comment: Try nesting inputs in block elements,

Comment: @PharsaThapa How? Which block? 

Comment: wrap input fields inside div. and declare display= block for style

Comment: @PharsaThapa It doesn't work. Besides, I am using display: flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stack them vertically on the breakpoint just add flex-direction

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.header-form input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=submit] {
   width: 70%;
 }
.header-flex {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
}
```

Comment: Yo man! I added it before though that didn't work then... But it's working now. Thanks my friend 

Answer (score 0):

This will be your html

```
<div class="header-form header-flex">

<div class = "myblock">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class = "myblock">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="myblock">
<input type="submit">
</div>
  
</div>
```

And CSS

```
/* Basic style */
.header-form input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=submit] {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
}


.header-form input[type=submit] {
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header-form input[type=submit]:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

/* Breakpoint style */
@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .header-form input[type=text],
  input[type=email],
  input[type=submit] {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .header-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
.myblock{
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: NOt a problem! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Since you are working with a **form** it's ideal to include the form element

So your html will be:

```html
<div class="header-form header-flex">
  <form action"" method="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi dude, I know about them. Since I am practicing, I ignore them. Thank you for the guide ❤

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite understand your question, but if what you wanted was to flex your input elements as the screen got to 768px then adding the form element fixes that by removing that weird button positioning

Comment: Hum, I see now... for some seconds, I totally forgot about the `form` tag. That's a problem with us, new coder :)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Enjoy your coding.